# Add event global callback in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an `onerror` function on `div.circle_thumb>img` event.

Now, I'm added `onerror event each img tag like this.

`<div class="circle_thumb" ><img src="some/url" onerror="this.src=url/to/replaced" /></div>`

But this bothering me too much.

Can I add this callback globally?

Comment: is the `this.src=url/to/replaced` exactly the same in all cases?

Comment: If by "globally" you mean to say the body or HTML element, then the answer is "no" as the [*error* event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-error) doesn't bubble.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, all `div.circle_thumb>img` will be replaced to that url on error.

Comment: @RobG It means, I wanna add the callback on all `div.circle_thumb>img` tags.

Comment: Ah, in that case, pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript like this

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.circle_thumb>img'), function(img) {
    img.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    this.src='../img/logo.png';
  });
});
```

or in ES2015+

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.circle_thumb>img')).forEach(img => img.addEventListener('error', e => img.src='../img/logo.png'));
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery version:

```
jQuery.each($('div.circle_thumb > img'), function(index, image){
    image.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        image.src='../img/logo.png';
    });
});
```